# Как в imagettftext указать шрифт с внешнего сайта

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой.

Нужно в imagettftext прописать шрифт с внешнего сайта.

Сейчас код выглядит так:

```
$font_txt = 'font_gen/Font.ttf';
imagettftext($im_end, $font_size, 0, $margin_x, $font_size+$margin_y-($height / 2), $black, $font_txt, $text_new);
```

В таком виде шрифт отображается в imagettftext исправно

.

Если в **$font_txt** указать путь к шрифту так **$font_txt = 'https://site.ru/dizain-market/font_gen/Font.ttf';**

То шрифт перестает работать и текст не показывается.

Как мне указать путь к шрифту с внешнего сайта?

Comment: можно загрузить файл с внешнего ресурса на свой сайт средствами php, а дальше будет работать ваш код выше

Comment: @ArchDemon Мне нужно изменить шрифт при смене стиля дизайна.

Я вот ещё думаю. Как добавить вместо ```'font_gen/Font.ttf';``` вставить переменную, которая содержит название шрифта. Пробовал вставить в таком виде ```'font_gen/'.$srift.'.ttf';``` но в таком виде тоже не выдает правильно текст

Comment: Решил проблему. Поправил переменную, и она заработала